# Можно ли упростить django template код?

Tags: django, шаблоны

```
        {% now "w" as w %}
        {% now "G" as h %}


         <div class="col s6">
             <table>
                 <tbody>
                 <tr {% if w == '1' %}class="{% if h <= '9' and h >= '15' %}red accent-3{% else %}teal{% endif %} white-text"{% endif %}>
                     <td class="pE">Понедельник</td>
                     <td class="qE">9:00–15:00</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr {% if w == '2' %}class="{% if h <= '9' and h >= '17' %}red accent-3{% else %}teal{% endif %} white-text"{% endif %}>
                     <td class="pE">Вторник</td>
                     <td class="qE">9:00–17:00</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr {% if w == '3' %}class="{% if h <= '9' and h >= '17' %}red accent-3{% else %}teal{% endif %} white-text"{% endif %}>
                     <td class="pE">Среда</td>
                     <td class="qE">9:00–17:00</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr {% if w == '4' %}class="{% if h <= '9' and h >= '17' %}red accent-3{% else %}teal{% endif %} white-text"{% endif %}>
                     <td class="pE">Четверг</td>
                     <td class="qE">9:00–17:00</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr {% if w == '5' %}class="{% if h <= '9' and h >= '17' %}red accent-3{% else %}teal{% endif %} white-text"{% endif %}>
                     <td class="pE">Пятница</td>
                     <td class="qE">9:00–17:00</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr {% if w == '6' %}class="{% if h <= '9' and h >= '17' %}red accent-3{% else %}teal{% endif %} white-text"{% endif %}>
                     <td class="pE">Cуббота</td>
                     <td class="qE">9:00–17:00</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr {% if w == '0' %}class="red accent-3 white-text"{% endif %}>
                     <td class="pE">Воскресенье</td>
                     <td class="qE">Закрыто</td>
                 </tr>
                 </tbody>
             </table>
         </div>
```

Еще бы хотелось производить запись в переменную. Если рабочий день, то 1, если не рабочий, то 0

Answer (score 0):

А что из вьюхи в шаблон передаете? Можно передавать список "дней недели" в шаблон, а затем итерироваться по нему:

```
{% for item in weekdays_list %}
         <tr {% if w == '1' %}class="{% if h <= '9' and h >= '15' %}red accent-3{% else %}teal{% endif %} white-text"{% endif %}>
                 <td class="pE">{{ item }}</td>
                 <td class="qE">9:00–15:00</td>
         </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: в принципе weekdays можно сложить в темплейт тегс. отлично =)

Comment: хотя стоп. там есть воскресенье, где вообще закрыто и есть вт, ср, чт, пт, сб, где с 9 до 17

Comment: @RomualdShmidtelson Окей, что мешает сделать slice и обработать последний элемент по своему? Имею ввиду https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#slice